# How fix arguments error of HSET in Redis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am implementing a cacheing layer in NodeJS and MongoDB using Redis. I am fairly new to Redis. So I am having trouble where I am trying to automatically clear cache after a given timing. The error I am getting

```
ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command
```

This is my code block

```
mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = async function() {

  const key = JSON.stringify(
      Object.assign({}, this.getQuery(), {collection: 
      this.mongooseCollection.name})
  );
  const cachedValue = await client.hget(this.hashKey, key);

  if(cachedValue) {
      const parsedDoc = JSON.parse(cachedValue);

      return Array.isArray(parsedDoc) ? parsedDoc.map(doc => new 
      this.model(doc)) : new this.model(parsedDoc);
  }

  const result = await exec.apply(this, arguments);

  client.hset(this.hashKey, key, JSON.stringify(result), 'EX', 10);

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Redis `HSET` only accepts 3 arguments. If you want to store multiple keys in one call, you should use `HMSET`.

Reference:

https://redis.io/commands/hset

https://redis.io/commands/hmset

```
client.hmset(this.hashKey, key, JSON.stringify(result), 'EX', 10);
```

should work.

Comment: Since ["As per Redis 4.0.0, HMSET is considered deprecated. Please use HSET in new code."](https://redis.io/commands/hmset) how should we use hset instead?

Comment: @FredMaggiowski HSET can now accept multiple fields and values, just like HMSET used to.